# $T : \mathbb{R}^{5} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with: $\mathrm{span}[v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}] = \mathrm{null}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm supposed to find the linear transformation given these 3 vectors. EDIT: they are linearly independent! sry
I have just recently learned about span, linear combination, linear independence and basis. So my knowledge is quite limited here...

As the title says:

$T : \mathbb{R}^{5} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$

$\mathrm{span}[v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}] = \mathrm{null}(T)$, with $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3} \in \mathbb{R}^{5}$

Shouldn't matrix $A$ from $T$... ie **rref(A)** give me a linear combination that is $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$? That solves $Ax = 0$ so I presume that ok...? Or have I totally misunderstood something here... probably have...

I am given these vectors and I have to find $A$. And $A$ must be a $2 \times 5$ matrix? Since my transformation is going $\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$? Can the rref(A) then actually even create a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$?

Guys... help is **GREATLY APPRECIATED!**

Any tips etc. Thanks!

Comment: What is rref in your notation? Notice that you can exhibit infinite $T$ with this data. With these data I would assume $v_1, v_2, v_3$ linearly independent, that's ok. Suppose $(w_1,w_2,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis, to define a map you need to give the image of $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Comment: rref = row echelon form? I rref the matrix in the transformation. Is that wrong to say? And sorry! They are linearly independent yes! I've edited! Give the image of w1 and w2... what is w1 and w2? Sorry... :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll try to clarify a bit.

An important thing about linear transformation is that it is enough to define them on a basis, then the value for any other vector follows from linear combination:

for instance suppose you have a linear map $L:V \rightarrow W$ between vector spaces and $(v_1 , \dots , v_n)$ is a basis for $V$. Then any vector $v$ is uniquely written as $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i v_i$ and then $L(v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i L(v_i)$. Thus you can see it is enough to know the $L(v_i)$'s.

Well, now we come to our problem. You have a map $T: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. In general, if you have a linear map $L:V \rightarrow W$ between finite dimensional real vector spaces, you have $\dim V= \dim Im(L) + \dim ker(L)$. In our case, since the target space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, the image has at most dimension 2. Hence the kernel has at leas dimension 3 (that's why I pointed out your vector have to be linearly independent).

Now you are give 3 linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. You know you can complete a set of linearly independent vectors to a basis. Say $(w_1,w_2,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis (note that the order in a basis is important, since we are going to write a matrix).

Now, from your data, there is a lack of information. I mean... The kernel is supposed to have dimension 3, since you say it is spanned by $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Then to define a map we have to determine the image of $w_1$ and $w_2$. By hypothesis about the kernel we only know that $T(w_1)$ and $T(w_2)$ have to be non-zero and linearly independent (the kernel has dimension 3).

That's why we can not define a map. For instance, suppose $v_1=e_3$, $v_2=e_4$, $v_3=e_5$, then you can take $w_1=e_1$, $w_2=e_2$ and you can define
$T(e_1)=e_1$, $T(e_2)=e_2$, $T(e_3)=0$, $T(e_4)=0$, $T(e_5)=0$
but you can also set
$T(e_1)=e_2$, $T(e_2)=e_1$, $T(e_3)=0$, $T(e_4)=0$, $T(e_5)=0$

What you can say (and here we come to the form of the matrix), that if we take a basis $(w_1,w_2,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ for $\mathbb{R}^5$ and $(z_1,z_2)$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, in these basis the matrix has the form
$\left(\begin{matrix} a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ with $\det \left(\begin{matrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right) \neq 0$.

What you can do is the following: suppose you have fixed the basis $(z_1,z_2)$; since the map $T$ is surjective, you can find $x_1,x_2$ such that $T(x_1)=z_1$, $T(x_2)=z_2$. Since $z_1,z_2$ are linearly independent, so are $x_1,x_2$. In addition, since their image is non-zero, they are not in the kernel. So you can fix the basis $(x_1,x_2,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and with respect to this basis and to the basis $(z_1,z_2)$ the map $T$ is represented by
$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$